# React aggrid latest received message on top

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

We have incoming streaming data\messages on a solace topic, streaming data rate is high, let's say approx. 1000 msg\sec. We are planning to have this data on ag grid (used across our project.)

One of the requirements is that new incoming message needs to be added to the top row.

There are few ways which would achieve this like:

1. this.props.api.updateRowData({ add: [result], addIndex: 0 }); using
2. a custom sort on time field
3. using deltasort -->
   https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/data-update-transactions/#delta-sorting

I was wondering if anyone has previous experience in implementing such a scenario and pros and cons of each method. My main concern is on performance.

Since we always need to show the incoming message on top, so we can say data is already sorted for us. So if I apply 2) I am not sure which sorting algo ag-grid uses internally.

Any insights on this would be appreciated. Thanks.